# Run thread with object lifetime

Tags: c++, multithreading

In my class `A` there is a thread running as long as the objects lifetime. For now i have a boolean member variable that is checked every loop and at the destructor this variable is set to false.

```
class A {
public:
    A() : mRun(true) {
        mThread = std::thread(&A::DoWork(), this);
    }

    ~A() {
        mRun = false;
    }

private:
    bool        mRun;
    std::thread mThread;

    void DoWork() {
        while (mRun) {
            ...
        }
    }
};
```

is it possible to use `while(true)` safely? i read that on the destruction of threads, they will be terminated.

Comment: Use `std::atomic_bool` instead. It is thread safe whereas your example is not.

Comment: @Phantom: His sample isn't thread safe even with atomic bool, since it destroys the thread while it's still running

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"is it possible to use while(true) safely?"*

Yes it is (supposed *`while(true)`* actually means `while (mRun)`). You need to make that `mRun` member safe for concurrent read/write access from different threads. The simplest way to do so, is using a [`std::atomic<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) value, as follows:

```
class A {
public:
    A() : mRun(true) {
        mThread = std::thread(&A::DoWork(), this);
    }

    ~A() {
        mRun = false; // <<<< Signal the thread loop to stop
        mThread.join(); // <<<< Wait for that thread to end
    }

private:
    std::atomic<bool>        mRun; // Use a race condition safe data 
                                   // criterium to end that thread loop
    std::thread mThread;

    void DoWork() {
        while (mRun == true) {
            ...
        }
    }
};
```

where `mRun == true` should fallback to the [`std::atomic::operator T()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_T) function.

Answer (score 1):

**For a direct explanation of how to make the OP's problem thread safe, read the first paragraph. The rest describes an alternate way of doing exit conditions.**

Yes you can use `while(mRun)` in your code safely. To make your existing example thread safe call `mthread.join()` so that the thread does not have it's destructor execute while the thread is still running.

---

Another way of controlling thread execution is to use exceptions and exception handlers to escape the thread loop. This is accomplished by using a try catch statement outside the loop. This is the method `boost::thread` uses So in your method you would call `my_thread.interrupt_check()` and this would throw an exception. This would allow the stack to be unwound and any objects on the stack to be destroyed. But you have to be careful using this method. If the exception is not caught in the thread the program will call `std::terminate` and your entire program will stop. An example for this method would be something like this:

```
void interrupt_check();

class interruptible_thread
{
private:
    static thread_local std::atomic<bool>* interrupt_flag;
    friend void interrupt_check();

    std::atomic<bool> flag;
    std::thread thread_obj;

    struct interrupt_exception { };

public:
    template<typename _Fn, typename... _Args>
    interruptible_thread(_Fn& function, _Args& arguments) :
        flag(false),
        thread_obj([](std::atomic<bool>* flag_var, _Fn&& function, _Args&& arguments)
            { interrupt_flag = flag_var; 
              try
              {
                  function(std::forward<_Args>(arguments));
              } catch (interrupt_exception& e) { }
            },
            &interrupt_flag,
            std::forward<_Fn>(function),
            std::forward<_Args>(arguments))
    { }

    void interrupt() { flag = true; }

    ~interruptible_thread() { flag = false; interrupt(); thread_obj.join(); }
}

void interrupt_check()
{
    if(!interruptible_thread::interrupt_flag)
        throw interruptible_thread::interrupt_exception;
}
```

The advantages to this method are that destructors get executed properly and that it is possible to terminate the thread when the caller wishes. The disadvantages are if the thread does not check then this is simly `std::thread` with more overhead.

Also note that, if the `std::thread` object is destroyed while the thread is still joinable `std::terminate` is called. I imagine that is not the intention of wrapping the thread in an object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that mRun will ONLY be set to false, as the object is being destroyed.  Being that it is on its own thread, this is NOT a good idea.  A better idea is to use a global boolean that is set, that this class can use atomic operations on, to prevent two threads from writing to it, (say, thread A sets it to FALSE, while thread B is RIGHT BEHIND it, and sets it back to TRUE, for whatever reason--bad idea...), THIS way, as the object is destroyed, you can detect that it no longer exists, and not attempt to access it.

When I do stuff like this, I tend to pass an instance of the thread itself into my RUN function, so I can access it as like

```
while(threadInstance->mRun)
```

But this might not work for you.